# data studio emailed report pages not in correct order

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, looker-studio

My google data studio report is 9 pages of custom google analytics data visualization and some custom goals from tag manager. Doesn't matter. When the emailed pdf arrives (as well as the 5 page preview in the email body), the whole report is out of order! Page 1 becomes page 8, page 3 is page 9, etc.. etc..

Is there a way to specify the order? Because they're in the report the way that I want them when viewing or editing or looking at the pages tab and how I'd want it to download. Like, page 1-9 is how I want it. Instead I'm getting 8,9,3,6,2,7,1,4,5...

I really need help please this is for a client and needs to be sent out asap

[Pages Order (As Desired)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es0NP.png)

[Title Of First Page Of Emailed Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVH4U.png) (Not what it should be...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google acknowledged that this was a bug and a fix is in the pipeline for Dec 1st 2021.

[The related thread in data studio community](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/134057535?hl=en)

Comment: yup i literally commented in that thread homie, thanks :)